# Why does Xcode say "expected declaration" with an arrow pointing to the word "timer"?

Tags: swift, xcode

I get an error on the line below `func pauseAction` that says "expected declaration" and there is an arrow pointing to the word "timer"

```
var timeLeft = 10
var timer = Timer()
var score: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    }
}
@IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any) {
  score += 1
}
@IBAction func pauseAction(_ sender: Any) {

}

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target:self, selector: Selector(("updateTimer")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
func updateTimer() {
    timeLeft -= 1
    timeLabel.text = String(timeLeft)
    if timeLeft == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case *expected declaration* means the code must be inside a method / function for example

```
func startTimer()
{
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target:self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```